# 1 VPS with 2 IP addresses. How to make them independent?

Tags: networking

I have this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto ens3

iface ens3 inet static

        address 46.xx.xxx.1x7
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        broadcast 46.38.xxx.255
        gateway 46.xx.xxx.1

auto ens3:0

iface ens3:0 inet static

    address 188.xx.xx.xx5
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

This is my present network setup on my VPS.

I have two public IP's, but I wish the traffic they made would not mix. 
I verify that all data leaves the VPS normally by one of two IP's.
As for the input, the data to reach the interface ens3:0 passes through the interface ens3.
I want the interfaces of my VPS to be independent. It will be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The question is, what exactly do you want to get.

For example, you can configure to run multiple daemons on multiple IPs. For example, you can configure an ssh daemon on 46.xx.xxx.1x7, and some different service (for example, an embedded sftp server) on 188.xx.xx.xx5.

The most typical solution in these scenarios if we have totally different webserver instances on the different IPs.

In most daemon configurations, you can give not only the port number, but also an IP address. For example, you can configure not only port `:80`, but also with an IP, `188.xx.xx.xx5:80`. In this case, that server will `listen()` on 188.xx.xx.xx5.

In these settings, the IP 0.0.0.0 has a special meaning, which is the default: the server listens on all available IPs.

Comment: For example: I intend to route specific UDP ports through different IP's.

Let's imagine: In my VPS I have two UDP ports that I want to access. (1500 and 1505) I want to access port 1500 using iface ens3 and port 1505 using iface ens3:0.

Did I make myself understood?

Comment: What has to do this anything with routing? Routing to where?

Comment: How will I explain?
I'll try....
I have two VPS, both of which communicate with each other using UDP ports.
Now notice, when I add in VPS(b) 46.xx.xxx.1x7:1500 it will also connect to port 1505.
I wanted to route IP 46.xx.xxx.1x7 to port 1500 and IP 188.xx.xx.xx5 to port 1505. (inbound and outbound connectivity)
Two independent interfaces with internet connection and isolated from one another.
You got it? It's possible?

Comment: @Douro You write: *"I wanted to route IP 46.xx.xxx.1x7 to port 1500 and IP 188.xx.xx.xx5 to port 1505"* "Routing an IP to a port" is unclear non-sense, a crap. You are playing with me?

Comment: @Douro I inserted your missing info into your question, I changed my upvote to a down, and then I gave it the last required close vote. Now your question is downvoted, and closed, although it has already more info as you originally wrote. Extend your question to a clear one, so I will be able to change my vote, and maybe it will be reopened. After 9 days, your question will be deleted automatically.

Comment: @Douro The problem is that your communication clearly shows that you could formulate clearly -> I think you are playing with the site on an unknown reason. I am very sad that initially I saved your question :-( Explain your virtual network topology, and don't miss any important info. Or, good bye.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm not kidding at all. I seek help and can not explain myself.
I'll try to simplify my question ...
I want the interfaces of my VPS to be independent. Without the traffic of ens3:0 interface pass by ens3 interface.